# What is the second save Aberforth did to Harry's team?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2* (2011), Hermione speaks about Aberforth:

> Hermione: He did save our lives **twice**. Kept an eye on us in that
> mirror.

What is the second save Aberforth did to Harry's team?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First save: He sent Dobby to Malfoy Manor to rescue Harry, Ron, and Hermione.

> ‘It’s your eye I’ve been seeing in the mirror.’
>
> There was silence in the room. Harry and the barman looked at each
> other.
>
> **‘You sent Dobby.’**
>
> **The barman nodded** and looked around for the elf.
>
> <sub><sup>[Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/136251.Harry_Potter_and_the_Deathly_Hallows)</sup></sub>

Second save: He covered up for them when they accidentally set off a Caterwauling charm while apparating into Hogsmeade.

> The Dementors had retreated, the stars were popping out again, and the
> footsteps of the Death Eaters were becoming louder; but before Harry
> in his panic could decide what to do, there was a grinding of bolts
> nearby, a door opened on the left-hand side of the narrow street and a
> rough voice said, ‘Potter, in here, quick!’
>
> He obeyed without hesitation: the three of them hurtled through the
> open doorway.
>
> ‘Upstairs, keep the Cloak on, keep quiet!’ muttered a tall figure,
> passing them on his way into the street and slamming the door behind
> him.